# ¿Cómo comprimir el contenido de un directorio con la ruta almacenada en mysql con php?

Tags: php, mysql, zip

Tengo una tabla en 'index.php' que me muestra los registros de la tabla 'tablazip' de la base de datos 'ejemplozip'.

```
<div class="container">
                <table class="table table-hover display" id="mitabla">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                            <th scope="col">Archivos</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                        <?php

                            include "conexion.php";
                            $consulta = "SELECT * FROM tablazip";
                            $resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta);
                            while($fila=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                                echo "<td>"; echo $fila['id']; echo "</td>";
                                echo "<td>"; echo $fila['nombre']; echo "</td>";
                                //echo "<td>"; echo $fila['archivos']; echo "</td>";

                                echo "<td><a href='descargar.php?id=".$fila['id']."'> <button type='button' name='descargar' class='btn btn-info'>Descargar</button></a></td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

En el comentario, me muestra la ruta almacenada, por decir

> docmn/archivos1/

Y dentro de 'archivos1' hay múltiples archivos en PDF.

**Me gustaría saber cómo puedo comprimir todo el directorio y su contenido.**

Añado que el archivo 'conexion.php' tiene lo siguiente

```
<?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'ejemplozip');

    if($mysqli->connect_error){

        die('Error en la conexion' . $mysqli->connect_error);

    }
?>
```

Y que el archivo 'descargar.php' solo comprueba que se recibe el 'id' del registro.

```
<?php 

    require 'conexion.php';

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    var_dump($id);
?>
```

Comment: Usa la función glob() para obtener el contenido del directorio: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php

Comment: @Triby gracias, lo intentaré c: